# Get serialized response of all models related to base model instance using Django REST framework

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, foreign-keys

I have 3 models

```
class Project(models.Model):

      project_name=models.CharField(_("Project Name"), max_length=50)
      ...............................................................

class Calculations(models.Model):
      project = models.ForeignKey("address.Project", verbose_name=_("Project"), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
      ...................................................................................................

class Finances(models.Model):
      project = models.ForeignKey("address.Project", verbose_name=_("Project"), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
      ...................................................................................................
```

each entry in model **Project** is connected to 2 entries in **Calculation** model. Also, each entry of **Calculation** is connected to 4 entries of **Finance** model

Is there any way to get serialized response by using only the primary_key of the base **Project** model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what was needed is just to pass the project instance into the project serializer

```
project_instance = Project.objects.get(id=project_id)
serializer = ProjectSerializer(instance=project_instance)
return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```